# columnwise sum matching values to another column

Tags: r

Seems, I am missing some link here.
I have data frame

```
df<-data.frame(w=sample(1:3,10, replace=T), x=sample(1:3,10, replace=T), y=sample(1:3,10, replace=T), z=sample(1:3,10, replace=T))

> df
   w x y z
1  3 1 1 3
2  2 1 1 3
3  1 3 2 2
4  3 1 3 1
5  2 2 1 1
6  1 2 2 3
7  1 2 2 2
8  2 2 2 3
9  1 3 3 3
10 2 2 1 1
```

I want to get the number of rows of each column which matches to 1st column.

```
sum(df$w==df$x)
[1] 3

 sum(df$w==df$y)
[1] 2
 sum(df$w==df$z)
[1] 1
```

I know using apply, I can do rowwise or colwise operations.

```
 apply(df,2,length)
 w  x  y  z 
10 10 10 10
```

How do I combine these two functions?

Comment: You can combine them by `apply(df[-1],2,function(cl) sum(df[,1]==cl))` but @David's solution should be a way more effective, especially on large data sets.

Answer (score 4):

Try `colSums`

```
colSums(df[-1] == df[, 1])
# x y z 
# 3 2 1
```

Or if you into `*apply` loops could try

```
vapply(df[-1], function(x) sum(x == df[, 1]), double(1))
```

Comment: Great, thanks. [rant: why do I have to wait 10 mins to accept answer]

Comment: @DavidArenburg Using `data.table`, `setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x==df[[1]])), .SDcols=-1]`.  Not sure if this is efficient as `vapply`

Comment: @akrun I was thinking about that, but it just looked like overcomplicating compared to just `colMeans`...